# How can I solve a functional equation?

Tags: equation-solving

Consider a relation like:

```
x/(4 + x) f[x] == f[1/(x + 1)]
```

Is there a way to use Mathematica to determine whether a solution `f[x]` to this equation exists and what the solution is?

Comment: These are called functional equations, and literature exists on them.  In general, they are very difficult to solve.  Search on "functional equation" at this site to find several examples, or with Google for references.  You also might try [math.SE].

Answer (score 2):

Well,

```
f[x_] := 0;
```

is one solution.

Otherwise, I suspect there is no way to find a formula for another solution, but we can give an interesting condition for its existence.  If a function satisfies the functional equation, then it seems to be the limit of an infinite product of factors greater than `1`.

```
ClearAll[f];
frule = f[x_] :> f[1/(x + 1)]/(x/(4 + x));


Nest[# /. frule &, f[x], 6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One set of factors approach `3 + GoldenRatio` except for `x` near `-GoldenRatio`:

```
Plot[{(4 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + x)))), (4 + 1/(
    1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + x))))) , (4 + 1/(
    1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + x))))))}, {x, -4, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another set of factors approach `GoldenRatio` except for `x` near `-GoldenRatio`:

```
Plot[{(1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + x)))), (1 + 1/(
    1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + x))))) , (1 + 1/(
    1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + 1/(1 + x))))))}, {x, -4, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is another factor in the nested expression `f[...]`, where the inside is a convergent of the continued fraction for `GoldenRatio - 1` (or `1/GoldenRatio`).  So `f[x]` must approach zero as `x` approached `GoldenRatio - 1` as rapidly as the other factors approach infinity.  Here I run out of ideas.  The products do not look familiar to me, but other may know what to do with them.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting read!